# UITableView doesn't reload data

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

I'm recently working on an app which allows users add items into the order list, and they can press a button to call out a popover table view, and I'm using core data to store the data.

The app has a main table view, and each row will brings up another table view, just like the Facebook app that has a sliding menu.

The layout of the app looks like the following:

```
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
|                                                ______________ |
|                                               |Popover Button||
|                                                -------------- |
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
|-----------------------------|First table item 1               |
|Row to call the First table  |                                 |
|-----------------------------|---------------------------------|
|Row to call the Second table |First table item 2               |
|-----------------------------|                                 |
|Row to call the Third table  |---------------------------------|
|-----------------------------|First table item 3               |
|Row to call the Fourth table |                                 |
|-----------------------------|---------------------------------|
```

The problem is occurred in the following scenario:

1. Launch the app.
2. Select the first table view.
3. Pressed the add button to add some items into the list.
4. Press the popover button to see the popover table view (the list has been updated).
5. Close the popover table view.
6. Further add some more items into the list.
7. Press the popover button (the list stay the same, the table view hasn't been updated).
8. Go to another table view (or call the same table view again)
9. Press the popover button again (the list has then been updated).

Could anyone help me to sort it out? Thanks!

Below is the code:

OrderView.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    //load lists
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Dish"];
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"created" ascending:YES]];

    self.lists = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    return [(AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    // Delete the row from the data source

        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:[self.lists objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];

        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Dish"];
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"created" ascending:YES]];

        self.lists = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];

        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
```

DetailView.m

```
- (IBAction)popupAddToOrderButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    OrderViewController *orderView = [[OrderViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OrderViewController" bundle:nil];
    Dish *newList = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Dish" inManagedObjectContext:orderView.managedObjectContext];
    newList.created = [NSDate date];
    newList.title = self.popupTitle.text;
    [orderView.managedObjectContext save:nil];
    orderView.lists = [orderView.lists arrayByAddingObject:newList];
}
```

Comment: I haven't debugged your code above to determine why the table isn't displaying the new data but you are doing this the hard way. Check out the docs for `NSFetchedResultsController`. It's designed to be the data source for a `UITableView` displaying data from a core data store and will make this implementation much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I used NSNotification to solve this issue as the NSNotification will go through the entire app, so I set a NSNotification receiver at the popover table view, and when the popover table view receives the notification, it will do the fetch request to get data.

And when the add button is pressed, it will send out the notification to ask the popover view to get the data.

So that's it, issue solved.